# Troublesome SQL CASE query

Tags: sql, switch-statement

A bit stuck on the below, can anyone identify where I'm going wrong? I think it's a simple case expression issue:

```
CASE when (ISNULL([6WeekSales].SalesQTY / 6 , 0)) >= (ISNULL([12WeekSales].SalesQTY / 12 , 0))
then
((dbo.ItemVendorDetails.LeadTime / 7 * CASE ISNULL([6WeekSales].SalesQTY / 6 , 0) - (ISNULL(ItemsStock.StockOnHand , 0) - ISNULL(SO.OpenQTY , 0) + ISNULL(PO.[Open PO's'] , 0)) - (dbo.ItemVendorDetails.LeadTime / 7 * CASE ISNULL([6WeekSales].SalesQTY / 6 , 0)) 
 ELSE ((dbo.ItemVendorDetails.LeadTime / 7 * CASE ISNULL([12WeekSales].SalesQTY / 12 , 0) - (ISNULL(ItemsStock.StockOnHand , 0) - ISNULL(SO.OpenQTY , 0) + ISNULL(PO.[Open PO's'] , 0)) - (dbo.ItemVendorDetails.LeadTime / 7 * CASE ISNULL([12WeekSales].SalesQTY / 12 , 0)) END
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is say when X is greater than Y then THIS QUERY else THAT QUERY

Comment: What info are you looking for?The question is unclear.Kindly edit it

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but seems like you are struggling with the formatting of brackets.

try this: -

```
select 
CASE when   (ISNULL([6WeekSales].SalesQTY / 6 , 0)) >= (ISNULL([12WeekSales].SalesQTY / 12 , 0)) 
    then (dbo.ItemVendorDetails.LeadTime / 7 * CASE ISNULL([6WeekSales].SalesQTY / 6 , 0) 
    - (ISNULL(ItemsStock.StockOnHand , 0) 
    - ISNULL(SO.OpenQTY , 0) 
    + ISNULL(PO.[Open PO's'] , 0)) 
    - (dbo.ItemVendorDetails.LeadTime / 7 * CASE ISNULL([6WeekSales].SalesQTY / 6 , 0))))
    ELSE 
    ((dbo.ItemVendorDetails.LeadTime / 7 * CASE ISNULL([12WeekSales].SalesQTY / 12 , 0) 
    - (ISNULL(ItemsStock.StockOnHand , 0) 
    - ISNULL(SO.OpenQTY , 0) 
    + ISNULL(PO.[Open PO's'] , 0)) 
    - (dbo.ItemVendorDetails.LeadTime / 7 * CASE ISNULL([12WeekSales].SalesQTY / 12 , 0)))) 
    END
```